# Make a shape to look like a button

Tags: android, android-button, android-drawable

I do have a group of buttons, which I am customizing using selector-shape. Here is the code and image of what i have so far:

CODE-bgbtn.xml

```
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
    <solid
      android:color="#004dfd" />
    <stroke
       android:width="1dp"
       android:color="#2f3436" />
    <corners
       android:radius="0dp" />
    <padding
       android:left="10dp"
       android:top="10dp"
       android:right="10dp"
       android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#425262"
            android:endColor="#51677d"
            android:angle="45" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#2f3436" />
        <corners
            android:radius="0dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

And the results of this:

[image]

I have applied the style only for first button, as you can see it looks too flat. How to make it look more as a button?

Comment: Try to improve your gradient section. Select the right colors to look more realistic. Use also `centerColor` in gradient tag.

Comment: @Shaiful, i dont want to make exact copy of usual buttons, this is the color that i want. As you might saw usual buttons have a shadow, how to achieve this?

Comment: If you want the shadow you might be interested using the 9-patch image. Very good for background.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_enabled="true"
            android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:padding="10dp" android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="@color/yourColor" android:endColor="@color/yourColor" android:angle="90"/>
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#3E4976" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp" android:bottomRightRadius="15dp" android:topLeftRadius="15dp" android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:padding="10dp" android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="@color/yourColor" android:endColor="@color/yourColor" android:angle="90"/>
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp" android:bottomRightRadius="15dp" android:topLeftRadius="15dp" android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape android:padding="10dp"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="@color/yourColor" android:endColor="@color/yourColor" android:angle="90"/>
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp" android:bottomRightRadius="15dp" android:topLeftRadius="15dp" android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And then setBackground for button

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
```